# TeamCity not showing the latest run result

Tags: teamcity

I am new to TeamCity. I am facing this issue. I have several tests running as part of a system test. Some of the tests after completing the run, shows result of an earlier day. Please see the image in the link below:

[image: Test result of an earlier day]
As you can see, it shows it was ran 3 days ago with a build number 164. But if I go to the log of that test, I can see the correct info
[image: Correct result]

If I run the same test again, it shows the build is outdated
[image: Build Outdated]

But even after completing this run, it shows the same result as in the first image.

Can someone please let me know what I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are generating history builds, you can check this article in the official Team City documentation.

[History builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/History+Build?_ga=2.75823701.1592513364.1618270764-2113473206.1616825975)

Comment: I had read this. For some reason, TC is considering even new builds as History build